# AddWithValue method does't exist in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

I am trying to connect with oracle database using `ASP.NET`. I have connected with the server.I need to execute a query. I tried below code, but it shows an error in `"AddWithValue"` method. How do i fix it?

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("param1", 1);
```

Comment: can u plz post the error as u get it?

Comment: Also, little bit more code will be helpful...

Comment: Have you added the `System.Data` namespace

Comment: Have you included `System.Data.OracleClient` Namespace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a guess since you haven't provided enough code to know for sure, but I have a hunch that your `cmd` object is an instance of `Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand`. Older versions of that object's `Parameters` collection don't have an `AddWithValue` method. (Reference: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/win.111/b28375/OracleParameterCollectionClass.htm)

The `System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand` object's `Parameters` collection, on the other hand, does have that method. (Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracleparametercollection(v=vs.110).aspx)

However, the latter is deprecated, so you should probably stick with the former, but change your code to use the `Add` method instead. Or try to find a later version of Oracle's component, which I believe has introduced the `AddWithValue` method. (Not sure about that, though...)

Answer (score 0):

In your code, add this line as header : `System.Data.SqlClient` and in Solution Explorer, right click References->Add Reference->Frameworks. Scroll down to `System.Data` add select it using the check box, and goto Entension, above Frameworks and select `System.Data.SqlClient`

Comment: You can't just switch to components that aren't the same as the database connection you're using...